# Select specific item in Arraylist of arrays

Tags: arrays, arraylist, processing

I'm working with Processing and I have an Arraylist of arrays

ArrayList< ICurve []> c = new ArrayList< ICurve []> ();

I need to select a specific item in a specific array of my arraylist, but I can't understand how to do it. I know how to iterate inside the arraylist with the for cycle, but I can't understand how to select the item with a specific index.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Arraylist of arrays returns an array, so just use bracket notation:

```java
ArrayList <Integer[]> a = new ArrayList <Integer[]> ();    
void setup(){
    a.add(new Integer[] {1,2,3});
    println(a.get(0)[1]);// prints 2
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList< int[] > myArrayList = new ArrayList< int[]> ();
void setup()
{

  int[] myArray = {0, 1, 2, 3};
  myArrayList.add(myArray);
  println(myArrayList.get(0)[0]);

}
```

I've used a primitive datatype in this example, but the same principle applies.